# How to filter by property in Gremlin (if exist)?

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop, graph-query

I am new Gremlin and having trouble with filtering by property.

`A -> B`

Assume `A` and `B` are vertices and has edge between them with properties `Created_on` and `deleted_on`.

`deleted_on` property will be added only at the time of deletion.

How list by the edge property?

```
g.V(id).outE('Label').has('deleted_on', lt(timestamp.now())).outV().elementMap()
```

The above query returns empty, because the `deleted_on` property is not added to the edge yet.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure but I think you are looking to find all connections where the `deleted_on` property is less than `now`  or it does not exist.  If that is the case then you can use the [or()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#or-step) and [hasNot()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#has-step) steps in Gremlin to accomplish this similar to the query below.

```
g.V(id).
  outE('Label').
  has('deleted_on', lt(timestamp.now())).
  or().
  hasNot('deleted_on').
  outV().
  elementMap()
```